# Insufficient space on Android 6 with SD-Card mouted as internal storage

Tags: google-play-store, internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, adoptable-storage

I've got a Motorola Moto G 3 with Android 6.0
I installed a 32 GB SD-Card and I mounted it as Internal Storage (the new feature in Android 6). After installing some apps I get the error 'Insufficient memory' in the play store. Looking in the memory tab in the settings menu I saw that the internal storage is nearly full but with a filemanager I see that I have 25 GiB of storage left.
I have enabled the device encryption and I have enabled remote debugging in the developers setting.
(UI-tweaker is enabled too)

Has anyone an idea?
Thanks for your help!

Regards Microgamer

Comment: Have you tried moving some of the apps to the SD Card?  I believe you still need to do this even though you format the card as adopted storage.

Comment: It works logical as one storage...

Comment: Oh ups. It works logical as one storage and you can't move all apps. I can only move some but it doesn't helps much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is navigate to

**Settings** -> **Apps** -> *select a large app* -> **Storage**

Here it appears some apps have the option to **Change** the storage, while others do not - developers have to implement this.

If you have a **Change** button, then a menu appears where you can select the **SD card** and transfer the app.

I fear you'll have to go through all your large apps manually and try to free up space.

Another option would be to **delete the cache** of the apps on your internal storage.

---

[Here](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable) you can read about how Android deals with adoptable storage.

Comment: In the meanwhile I moved to Android 7.1.2 and some time ago I found that button too. But that confused me because my understanding of one storage is not two storages that are separated for the OS but together for every other app. Maybe the implementation or description of Android is wrong. I don't know. The storage thing was and still is strange for Android.